# Using wpdb to connect to a separate database

Tags: database, wpdb, mysql

I want to connect `wpdb` to another database. How do I create the instance and pass it the database name/username/password?

Thanks

Comment: Another MySQL database, or another database type?  Do you still want access to the regular WordPress database, or are you moving the site from one DB to another?

Comment: Yes, another MySQL database. It's a separate DB on the same server, and it's not a Wordpress one. It's a custom db, with information I want to display inside wordpress.

Comment: If you did that with the $wpdb object, if it were even possible, it would disconnect the rest of WordPress from its existing database. So, not recommended. Another option is to create a new instance using EZSQL, which is used by WordPress. I think EZSQL is used because it's a layer that abstracts you from having to use php-pdo-mysql, php-mysql, or php-mysqli, not knowing which might be installed on a given server.

Comment: Yes it's possible. wpdb can be instantiated to access any database and query any table.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

The wpdb object can be used to access any database and query any table. Absolutely no need to be Wordpress related, which is very interesting.

The benefit is the ability to use all the wpdb classes and functions like `get_results`, etc so that there's no need to re-invent the wheel.

Here's how:

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($rows as $obj) {
   echo "<li>".$obj->Name."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Booyah. Too bad all those comments added up on the question itself to block your accurate answer.

Comment: @Jeremy Clarke: I agree. Hoping our fellow wordpressers will be more careful to not innocently spread out disinformation.

Comment: you can also save time by using `global $wpdb`. But before firing $wpdb->get_results method, you must include wp-load.php as: 
 `require_once('/your/wordpress/wp-load.php');`

Comment: Set WPDB prefix to make WP_Query and get_post to generate correct sql query by calling `$mydb->set_prefix('wp_');`

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I can't help but feel squashing the `$mydb` variable with a new object could leave a connection open (I could be wrong). I would check to see if `$mydb` is already instantiated from a previous call, and if so, close the connection before spinning up a new instance.   eg (sorry can't do neat Markdown code blocks in the comments):
`if ($mydb != null) { $mydb->close(); }`

Comment: @JuniorMayhé I am unable to use `required_once` as it is giving me `PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required `

Comment: @M-R. How can wp_query be used afterwards. I am trying but then I get results of local wp, not remote db I am connecting with.

Answer (score 34):

Connecting to a second database is easy in WordPress, you simply create a new instance of the WPDB class and use it the same way you would use the standard $wpdb instance we all know and love.

Assuming the second database has the same login information as the main WP one you can even use the predefined constants from wp-config.php to avoid hardcoding the login information.

```
/**
 * Instantiate the wpdb class to connect to your second database, $database_name
 */
$second_db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $database_name, DB_HOST);
/**
 * Use the new database object just like you would use $wpdb
 */
$results = $second_db->get_results($your_query);
```

Comment: This is somewhat redundant to Wadih's answer but I think my code example is a bit clearer and its also important to remember the db login constant's as they are almost always the right ones to use and otherwise you risk issues when moving from dev->stage->live environments where the login details might change.

Comment: Set WPDB prefix to make WP_Query and get_post to generate correct sql query by calling `$second_db->set_prefix('wp_');`

Answer (score 23):

no one has said this so I thought I'd add an even easier way..

as long as your additional database has the same user/pass details to access it as your wordpress database you can use the database name before the table name like this

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM dbname.dbtable WHERE 1');
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: From my experience, this only works to _get_ data, i.e. using `SELECT`. You can't insert data.

Comment: it will not work externally,

Answer (score 11):

While these will work, you'll lose the ability to use the "other" custom features such as get_post_custom and wordpress queries. The simple solution is

```
$wpdb->select('database_name');
```

which changes the database system-wide (a mysql select_db). The database.table method works if you just want to make a simple query, but if you want to access another wordpress blog you can use select. You'll just need to change it back when you're done or your blog may do strange things.

Comment: I'm using this solution and it works great, except for one thing. For some unknown reason `wp_get_post_terms()` doesn't seem to use the newly selected DB?? Every other function I've tried (like `get_post_meta()`, `get_posts()` etc) seems to work just fine but `wp_get_post_terms()` seems to work towards the `DB_NAME` database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

I can't comment yet, but I wanted to expand on Wadih M.'s answer (which is great).

WP's database class is a customized version of Justin Vincent's ezSQL.  If you like the interface and you're wanting to do a site that's not WordPress-based, you might want to check it out: http://justinvincent.com/ezsql

Comment: ezSQL was really frustrating for me, coming from WPDB. No "prepare" statements, no "insert" or "update"... I like to use the entire WPDB class as it exists, which is possible by including a couple files out of BackPress in your project.

Comment: @gabrielk The link is dead - new one is: [1]  [1]: http://justinvincent.com/ezsql

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with using `$wpdb` to connect to a second blog database from a parent site that needs to update two blogs. I used `$wpdb->select($dbname, $dbh)` to select the second database, but I was still getting results from the first database.

I resolved the problem by calling `wp_cache_flush()` to clear the WordPress cache before calling WP functions on the second database.