# Getting post-thumbnails from another WP site

Tags: sidebar, widgets, posts, images

I have two WordPress installations, one at http://inversekarma.in and the other at http://inversekarma.in/photos. The latter is a photoblog, and its theme uses the standard WP post thumbnails (**EDIT:** featured images, to be precise!). Is there a way to show the most recent thumbnails from the second site on my first site's sidebar?

Comment: Are these two blogs in the same database with different prefixes, are they separate databases, or are the sites on separate servers?

Comment: @Mike: The two websites are on the same server, but use different databases with different prefixes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are (at least) **two (2) ways** to approach this:

1. You can **query the second database** which will require you to maintain the database credentials in two places, or at least in an include file, or
2. You could **create a simple JSON feed** for your photo blog and consume the feed on your main blog and cache it for a short time. This will cause a slight latency on page load when the cache expires but since both are on the same machine it shouldn't be an issue.

Let me know which you'd prefer and if I'll update the answer to so you how.

### UPDATE

To connect to another database you can read more about it here:

- [**Using wpdb to connect to a separate database**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/)

So here's what I hacked together for you, a function called `show_thumbnails_2nd_db()` which you can copy into your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function show_thumbnails_2nd_db() {
  global $wpdb;
  global $table_prefix;
  $save_wpdb = $wpdb;
  $save_prefix = $table_prefix;
  include_once(ABSPATH . '/photos/database-credentials.php');
  extract($database_credentials);
  $wpdb = new wpdb($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME, $DB_HOST);
  wp_set_wpdb_vars();

  // This is the code for featured images  
  $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('<img src="',attachment.guid,'"/>') AS url
FROM 
  {$wpdb->posts} attachment
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON attachment.ID={$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key='_thumbnail_id'
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id
WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_status='publish'
  AND attachment.post_type='attachment'
ORDER BY attachment.ID DESC
LIMIT 10
SQL;
  $post_urls = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
  if (is_array($post_urls))
    echo implode("\n",$post_urls);

// This is the code for post thumbnails  
//   $sql = <<<SQL
// SELECT DISTINCT {$wpdb->posts}.ID
// FROM {$wpdb->posts}
// INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} attachment
//    ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID=attachment.post_parent
// WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_status='publish'
//   AND attachment.post_type='attachment'
// ORDER BY attachment.ID
// LIMIT 10
// SQL;
//   $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
//   foreach($post_ids as $post_id) {
//     $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
//     if ($thumbnail) {
//       echo $thumbnail;
//     }
//   }
  $table_prefix = $save_prefix;
  $wpdb = $save_wpdb;
}
```

**Note:** That the above assumes you have created a `database-credentials.php` in the root of your photos blog, and it should look like this:

```
<?php    
$database_credentials = array(
  'DB_NAME' =>  'your_database',
  'DB_USER' =>  'your_db_user',
  'DB_PASSWORD' =>  'your db password',
  'DB_HOST' =>  'localhost',
  'table_prefix' => 'your_photos_db_prefix_',
);
```

Then **inside the `/wp-config.php` for your *photos* blog** you would replace the sections of code that look like this:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'your_database');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'your_db_user');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your db password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

And this:

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
```

With this:

```
include_once(ABSPATH . '/database-credentials.php');

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', $database_credentials['DB_NAME']);

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', $database_credentials['DB_USER']);

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', $database_credentials['DB_PASSWORD']);

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', $database_credentials['DB_HOST']);

$table_prefix  = $database_credentials['table_prefix'];
```

If you need more explanation just ask in the comments.

Comment: @Mike: My guess is, the first approach would be speedier. Am I correct? If we're going with this, can we read the `wp-config.php` of that installation? Is it safe to include the database password in a file elsewhere? And if we're going for the second approach, I would like a long cache delay, as I won't update my photoblog too frequently. Is there a caching plugin for this? I figure our job would be simpler if there was such a thing. Thanks!

Comment: @GPX: Yes it is faster to access via the database, but only when the cache is refreshed and it sounds like that could be done once per day?  Other than that it'd be a tiny bit slower. But it would be easier to use the database.

Comment: @GPX: I added an update, let me know what you think. Up votes and answer selects will be appreciated. :)

Comment: @Mike: OMG thanks so much for your code. I'll get home and try it out ASAP. BTW, modifying the `wp-config.php` file that way, is it safe? Would it affect future WP ugrades? Also, is there a chance it might break existing plugin functionality?

Comment: @Mike: And adding another question - Why can't I read the DB properties right off of the `wp-config.php` file?

Comment: @Mike: Here's the update - I've just made all the code changes, but it doesn't seem to work! :-( Where do I start debugging?

Comment: @GPX - Yes it is safe, updates don't touch `/wp-config.php` and if they did it wouldn't be hard to fix. The `include` is just a way to put the code that is normally in one file into two. It's not a big deal. You can't call `/wp-config.php` because at the end if calls `/wp-settings.php` to bootstrap WordPress. You *could* write a parser that would read the file and look for values but I thought that would be slightly slower and if someone used variables to define them somehow it wouldn't work. In order to suggest how to debug I need to know the symptoms.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for the clarification. Now coming to the 'not working' part - well, the symptoms are - I don't see anything on the screen. I tried `echo` -ing all the values - works. But the `foreach` loop doesn't output anything!

Comment: @GPX - You are running `show_thumbnails_2nd_db()` and it is not showing any values, or you are just getting a white screen with no HTML output at all? If the former can you add `print_r($post_ids)` before the `for` loop in the function to see if the SQL query is returning any values? You *do* have some post thumbnails assigned, right?

Comment: @Mike - HTML is fine, I see no errors. It is not showing any values! I tried adding `print_r($post_ids). It only prints `Array ( )`.

Comment: @GPX - That tells me you have no attachments for your posts. Are you sure that your posts have attachments? Or maybe you have not correctly configured the files as I described? Are you sure you used the correct credentials? You did not just copy my examples but instead replaced with your database credentials, right?

Comment: Yes, each post has a post thumbnail (featured image, as the post edit page calls it). Everything else is in place. And I've used the correct credentials! And there's a typo in your sample code - in the last line, there's a `)` after `[table_prefix]`

Comment: @GPX - Do you realize that a *"featured image"* is not the same as a *"post thumbnail"*, right? *(And thanks for pointing out the typo, fixed.)*

Comment: @GPX - I've updated the code to show Featured Image. WordPress is painfully inconsistent in those two terms.

Comment: @Mike - Wow, I didn't know that. Okay so I've made the change now, and I'm back to my earlier symptoms - No values shown, and adding `print_r($post_urls)` only prints `Array ( )`.

Comment: @Mike - I snooped a little bit more, and tried echo-ing the `$sql` string. The actual query is here  - http://pastebin.com/BNjL8uTG. The query actually has my parent blog's table prefix! Is the query correct!?

Comment: @GPX - No it's not. Do you have an assignment to `$table_prefix = 'wp_';` *below* the code I gave you to add?

Comment: @Mike - No I don't. In fact, I tried printing the `$database_credentials` array too, and it is correctly having all the values it should.

Comment: @Mike - And echo-ing `$table_prefix` does display the photoblog's table prefix! I'm stumped :-(

Comment: @GPX - Where did you try echoing `$table_prefix`? Immediately after you assigned it? Did you try echoing `$database_credentials['table_prefix']'?

Comment: @Mike - I echoed both `$table_prefix` and `$database_credentials['table_prefix']` after the `$wpdb = new wpdb(..)` line. Both display the photoblog table prefix correctly. But the actual query (`$sql`) still remains the same!

Comment: @GPX - Add `echo $GLOBALS['table_prefix'];` immediately after `$wpdb = new wpdb(..)` and before `wp_set_wpdb_vars();` to see what it prints. If it's not the prefix you need then somehow your `$table_prefix` is getting reset in between. _(Look in `wp_set_wpdb_vars()` in `/wp-includes/load.php` line ~324 to see what it contains and why `$table_prefix` this is important.)*  Also I note I had a typo on my code using `$target_prefix` instead of `$table_prefix` *(which I've fixed)* but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: @Mike - `echo $GLOBALS['table_prefix'];` prints my parent blog's table prefix! And line 324 in `/wp-includes/load.php` too holds the same value. Can't I just hardcode the photoblog's table prefix in the `show_thumbnails_2nd_db()` method?

Comment: @GPX - I have no idea what's going on in your code. Yes you can hardcode the table prefix _(haven't you not already tried?)_ The only reason no to is it'll be in two places which is generally not good. But after 20 comments on one question, I think it's the best. :)

Comment: @Mike - Okay so I hardcoded it and it works!! But the whole images are displayed. I don't want to let the user download whole images and then visually resize them using CSS. How do I actually resize them?

Comment: @GPX - 20+ comments on this one question. Maybe it's time to ask another question to solve the new requirement? Otherwise I feel like I might be bound to answering follow ups on this one question for all eternity! :)

Comment: @Mike - I thought of setting a new record! Anyways, thanks a ton. I'm posting a new question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Mike's answer is great, but I would use a different SQL query, since the GUID of the attachment post can change when you change servers or move the blog. My version also gives you access to information of the blog post, which is useful if you want to link to it.

```
SELECT post.ID, post.post_title, attachment_meta.meta_value AS upload_relative_path
FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS post
    JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS post_meta ON (post_meta.post_id = post.ID AND post_meta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
    JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS attachment_meta ON (attachment_meta.post_id = post_meta.meta_value AND attachment_meta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file')
WHERE post.post_status = 'publish'
    AND post.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY post.post_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Instead of `_wp_attached_file` you can also get the `_wp_attachment_metadata` value, which contains extra info about the image and alternative sizes.

Comment: Can I just replace Mike's SQL query with yours? Because I see that you are selecting 3 columns while his does only 1. If I want only the originally uploaded image's URL, can I select just `attachment_meta.meta_value`? And how do I select the small or medium-sized thumbnail for the corresponding image?

Comment: @GPX: You can use it instead of Mike's query. `get_col()` selects just one column, if you want more you should use `get_results()`. And you can leave off the columns you don't need, it was just an example of getting more info about the post. As I said, you can try it with `_wp_attachment_metadata` and apply `unserialize()` to the returned value. This way you get an array with information about all other sizes.

Comment: @Mike - Your block of code works great! But I have no idea about `unserialize()`. Can you just show me how to get the thumbnail?

Comment: @GPX: Just try what I said: use `_wp_attachment_metadata` instead of `_wp_attached_file` in the query. Return only `attachment_meta.meta_value`. Apply `unserialize()` to each result, and `var_dump()` it to see the contents. The rest is PHP programming, you should be able to do that yourself.

Comment: Okay so I put together a crude hack based on your idea, as I really couldn't understand the `var_dump()` of the unserialized array. Check out my piece of code - http://pastebin.com/xzEbt2NL. It uses hardcoded thumbnail sizes. Can you (pretty) please show me how to do it properly via `unserialize`? Also, how do I make each thumbnail a hyperlink to its post?