# Displaying content from one WP site on separate WP site

Tags: database, outside-wordpress, wp-load.php

I have two totally separate WP websites setup.  Different domains, different databases.  I manage both of them and they are both hosted on a dedicated server.  I am trying to include some basic content that requires just a tad more than an RSS feed.  I need to pull data from SITE-1 and display it on SITE-2, using basic WP formatting from a loop.  Everywhere I've looked makes it seem impossible.  I've tried calling wp-load.php but can't get it to work, and am not sure if it is even the right way to go.  I have access to both sites' root servers, and even the server root if necessary.  Is there anyway to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah

```
$wpdb2 = new wpdb('dbuser', 'dbpassword', 'dbname', 'dbhost');

// get 10 posts, assuming the other WordPress db table prefix is "wp_"
$query = "SELECT post_title, guid FROM wp_posts
          WHERE post_status = 'publish'
           AND post_type = 'post'
          ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 10";

$someposts = $wpdb2->get_results($query, OBJECT);
foreach($someposts as $somepost)
  echo "<a href=\"{$somepost->guid}\">{$somepost->post_title}</a><br />";
```

Another way is to use the [HTTP api](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API):

Code in your first site, where you want to display the data:

```
$send = array(
  'body' => array(
    'action' => 'get_some_posts',
    // send other data here, maybe a user/password if you're querying senstive data
  ),
  'user-agent' => 'RodeoRamsey; '.get_bloginfo('url')
);

$response = wp_remote_post('http://yoursiteurl.com/', $send);
  if (!is_wp_error($response) && ($response['response']['code'] == 200)) echo $response['body'];
```

Code in your second site, in the theme's functions.php (or create a plugin):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'process_post_request');
function process_post_request(){
  if($_POST['action'] == 'get_some_posts'):
    $posts = new WP_Query();
    $query = array('posts_per_page' => 10);
    $posts->query($query);
    while ($posts->have_posts()):
      $posts->the_post(); // here's the usual loop
      ?>

      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      <?php the_content(); ?>

      <?php
   endwhile;
   die();
  endif;
}
```

The 2nd method is easier and more flexible from the "formatting" perspective. For example here you could easily echo the post thumbnail as html, while using the database approach it would be very hard for you to get the link to the thumbnail image...

Comment: Hm, either my comment hadn't posted or vanished. [`wp_remote_retrieve_body()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_retrieve_body) is little more convenient than manual checks and direct access to response fields. And if going this way caching is a must, HTTP requests are major performance killers.

Comment: yea, in this case he needs to replace the last two lines with `echo wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_post('http://yoursiteurl.com/', $send))`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  This works great to grab basic info.  Do you happen to know how to use it to grab custom fields from each post?  That would be great! Thanks!  (And sorry it took me so long to work on it.)

Comment: if you're using the second method, with `get_post_meta()`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "my_custom_field", true); ?> doesn't work, but <?php $customField = get_post_custom_values("my_custom_field"); echo $customField[0]; ?> does, however, it doesn't work for images.  I have images stored with each of the posts, and if I try   <?php $customField = get_post_custom_values("images"); echo $customField[0]; ?> (where "images" is my custom field name for the images), it doesn't work.  Neither does <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>.

Comment: do these functions work on the 2nd site on a normal page, like index?

Comment: Sorry for such a long delay in response.  I kept checking here but just quickly glancing, and turns out your last response was hidden!  To answer your question, no, these custom functions are not included in the recipient site. Should they be?

Comment: no, they should be inside the "while" loop. `get_post_meta` doesn't work for you because you didn't define the $post global variable...

Comment: Can I stick that in somewhere and it still work?

Comment: OOh I believe I may have figured my own answer out!  I placed " global $post, $wpdb, $wp_query; " before the "while" loop and it seems that get_post_meta is working!  If that's not proper PHP please, let me know :P

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to bundle this somehow and get it to work on a php site OUTSIDE of WordPress..... any thoughts?

Comment: yes, in your first site instead of wp_remote_post() use [PHP's CURL functions](http://www.google.ro/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=php+curl&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) to get content from your second site.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is very similar to this question:

- [**Getting post-thumbnails from another WP site**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6190/getting-post-thumbnails-from-another-wp-site/6208#6208)

Basically you just need to created the `$wpdb` using the security credentials for your other site. Take a look at my answer on that question and let me know if it does or does not answer your question, and if not why so I might be able to provide a better answer.