# There is way to improve this query? wordpress get post data and some meta data

Tags: query, wpdb

Suppose we have 2 blog with different database A and B. I want to get some post from Blog B to show them on Blog A. The problem comes when the posts have much metadata (custom field for example) that i want to retrive with the post. My current query is below but it takes more than 16 sec...

```
SELECT post.ID, post.guid, post.post_title, 
        attachment_meta.meta_value AS upload_relative_path, 
        test.meta_value AS publish_carlton, 
        extest.meta_value AS exp_date,
        pt.meta_value AS price_type,
        pa.meta_value AS price,
        post_title_EN.meta_value AS title_EN,
        post_title_DE.meta_value AS title_DE,
        post_title_FR.meta_value AS title_FR,
        post_title_ES.meta_value AS title_ES
FROM cs_posts AS post
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS post_meta ON (post_meta.post_id = post.ID AND post_meta.meta_key = 'service_service_a4_img_thumbnail_id')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS extest ON (extest.post_id = post.ID AND extest.meta_key = 'expiration_date')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS test ON (test.post_id = post.ID AND test.meta_key = 'vocs_carlton')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS pt ON (pt.post_id = post.ID AND pt.meta_key = 'service_price_type')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS pa ON (pa.post_id = post.ID AND pa.meta_key = 'service_price')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS post_title_EN ON (post_title_EN.post_id = post.ID AND post_title_EN.meta_key = 'custom_title_EN')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS post_title_DE ON (post_title_DE.post_id = post.ID AND post_title_DE.meta_key = 'custom_title_DE')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS post_title_FR ON (post_title_FR.post_id = post.ID AND post_title_FR.meta_key = 'custom_title_FR')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS post_title_ES ON (post_title_ES.post_id = post.ID AND post_title_ES.meta_key = 'custom_title_ES')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS attachment_meta ON (attachment_meta.post_id = post_meta.meta_value AND attachment_meta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file')

WHERE post.post_status = 'publish'
    AND post.post_type = 'service'
    AND test.meta_value = '1'
ORDER BY post.menu_order ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Solved with some php code, now it takes 0,0030 in total, much different from 16 sec!

```
$sql = "SELECT post.ID, post.guid, post.post_title, 
        attachment_meta.meta_value AS upload_relative_path, 
        test.meta_value AS publish_carlton
FROM cs_posts AS post
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS post_meta ON (post_meta.post_id = post.ID AND post_meta.meta_key = 'event_event_a4_img_thumbnail_id')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS test ON (test.post_id = post.ID AND test.meta_key = 'vocs_carlton')
    JOIN cs_postmeta AS attachment_meta ON (attachment_meta.post_id = post_meta.meta_value AND attachment_meta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file')

WHERE post.post_status = 'publish'
    AND post.post_type = 'event'
    AND test.meta_value = '1'
ORDER BY post.menu_order ASC
LIMIT 20";


$res = $wpdb2->get_results($sql);

//0.0030 
foreach ($res as $r) {

    $nsql = "SELECT post_meta.meta_value,post_meta.meta_key
             FROM cs_postmeta AS post_meta
             WHERE post_meta.post_id = '".$r->ID."';";
    $metares = $wpdb2->get_results($nsql);

    foreach($metares as $meta) {

        if ($meta->meta_key == 'event_price_adult')
            $r->price = $meta->meta_value;

        if ($meta->meta_key == 'custom_title_EN')
            $r->title_EN = $meta->meta_value;

        if ($meta->meta_key == 'custom_title_DE')
            $r->title_DE = $meta->meta_value;

        if ($meta->meta_key == 'custom_title_ES')
            $r->title_ES = $meta->meta_value;

        if ($meta->meta_key == 'custom_title_FR')
            $r->title_FR = $meta->meta_value;

    }


}


return ($res);
```

Comment: Is this a query that WordPress generates?

Comment: no it's a custom query, i use it in blog A to get post from blog B with different database

Comment: Why does it need to be improved?

Comment: It's very slow! it takes 16.7944 sec

Comment: What is the query supposed to do? Please [edit] your question, rephrase it, add more info about the use case, etc etc etc.

Comment: You can try rewriting as a `UNION` or try subqueries instead of `JOIN`s to get those titles. However, this kind of SQL optimization strikes me as far out of the scope of this site, and the query isn't going to be testable (and the question not useful) for anyone without your database. That makes it very localized as well.

Comment: related to this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38530/most-efficient-way-to-get-posts-with-postmeta

Comment: and to this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7152/displaying-content-from-one-wp-site-on-separate-wp-site

Comment: Is this question a follow up [on that question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139760/how-to-get-mixture-of-posts-from-different-blogs-in-multisite)?

Comment: unfortunately no, i know switch blog but in this case there are two different database