# Insert post in another database

Tags: database, wp-insert-post

I have developed a custom script that uses `wp_insert_post` to create new posts, however i'd like to use similar code to create the same data in another wp database.
Could be this done on the fly before insertion? For example instruct wordpress to point another database and then insert data?
Or should I do this "manually" using raw mySQL code?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid SQL altogether and use the XML-RPC API. This would also let you post to remote wordpress installs too.

*( note if XML-RPC is not an option, scroll further down )*

**If Using XML-RPC**

Here's some code from a quick google search using XML-RPC to post to a remote Wordpress blog:

http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/great-code-for-remote-posting?replies=5

Here's a simpler set of examples with an explanation of the XML-RPC APIs

http://life.mysiteonline.org/archives/161-Automatic-Post-Creation-with-Wordpress,-PHP,-and-XML-RPC.html

And here's an example from WP-Recipes using Curl and XML-RPC:

http://www.wprecipes.com/post-on-your-wordpress-blog-using-php

```
function wpPostXMLRPC($title,$body,$rpcurl,$username,$password,$category,$keywords='',$encoding='UTF-8') {
    $title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);
    $keywords = htmlentities($keywords,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);

    $content = array(
        'title'=>$title,
        'description'=>$body,
        'mt_allow_comments'=>0,  // 1 to allow comments
        'mt_allow_pings'=>0,  // 1 to allow trackbacks
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'mt_keywords'=>$keywords,
        'categories'=>array($category)
    );
    $params = array(0,$username,$password,$content,true);
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.newPost',$params);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $results;
?>
```

**If afterall that XML-RPC is not for you**

Perhaps a wordpress multisite might be best for you? Creating the new post would be as simple as calling `switch_to_blog($blog_id);` then doing your business creating the new post, before calling `restore_current_blog();`

**If you MUST use SQL**

Use [this question linked to](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database) by mike23 in order to gain access via a wpdb object

Comment: What advanatges using this technique versus mySQL?  
There's quite a bit of code here, maybe little less than using mySQL... maybe this wuold prevent potential conflicts with database scheme changes over newer WP versions?

Comment: Indeed, fewer conflicts, and you get all the hooks filters that plugins use, and side stuff wordpress stuff that you skip by going straight for the database.

Comment: You also gain the security of that API, whereas your SQL code hasnt been tested for years with years of bugfixing and security fixes

Comment: Your also freed from needing the SQL database on the same server ( and its more secure than having a public facing SQL server )

Comment: There's also stuff like user postcounts etc to take into account

Comment: And validation, e.g. if your SQL specifies an author that no longer exists, the SQL won't return a failure or fallback onto another value

Comment: Tom,I like the multiste "switch_to_blog" idea. I recall WP MU, once existed but now it should be packed within WP? Any performance issues?

Comment: Its not reccomended for shared servers, and there are performance costs to using switch_blog, use it as few times as you can, and cache when possible.

Comment: e.g. if you have 5 switch_blog calls itll be expensive. Also bear in mind that if you nest them and call restore_current_blog on the nested switch_blog, it will not return you to that blog, itll return you to the current blog. There are no 'stack push pop' semantics