# Switching database on the fly

Tags: database

I have read [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database) about switching the current wp database on the fly using

```
$wpdb->select('database_name');
```

Once done, I understand that i will have to issue the same statement to the original database.

Questions:

- Right after changing the database, do i need to flush caches or similar stuff to get things working properly? Will I need to call again WP header?
- Potential issues?

Comment: I don't think `select()` will switch the db :) That's used to select tables. Read the question you linked - you need to instantiate a new wpdb object, with the db name as one of the arguments...

Comment: It does. I'm testing this and seems working. As for the linked post, please read last posts from Matt & Dennis.

Comment: But how do you pass the user/password to connect to that database?

Comment: I'm using the same user/password for both the databases. Works perfectly!

Comment: `$wpdb->select()` is used to switch to a different database on the same server.  If your user doesn't have access, it won't work.  It internally calls `mysql_select_db()` and passes in the database name.

Comment: @EAMann, that's the case. Same server, same username/password. Works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works!

This is the code, assuming both the databases share the same username & password:

```
$wpdb->select('mydbname');
wp_cache_flush();
```

Once done, re-issue the same statements, with the original database name.

Can't see any performance issue at the moment, maybe because this is done when building a custom form picking data from two posts out of two databases. 
It may impact performance when used on a large amount of rows in batch loop...

Comment: Omg thank you! I've been going absolutely crazy trying to import users from an old WP DB and `wp_insert_user` kept saying "Username exists". `wp_cache_flush` was the answer.