# php include not working in custom page

Tags: php, mysql, include

#### The Problem

I have a `db.php` file which contains mysql login details. I want it in a separate file like this so it can be linked in several different pages for easier tracing later.

This all works when not on a wordpress site, but I'm trying to convert everything over to wordpress now and I'm encountering a problem.

The below doesn't work (echoes nothing on page), but if I copy the single line from `inc/db.php` into my `page-pricechanges.php` it works.

What's the best way for me to link this?

---

#### Structure

\THEMEFOLDER

- \page-pricechanges.php
- \header-pricechanges.php
- \inc\db.php

---

#### Page code

**header-pricechanges.php**

```
<head>
    <?php  
        include 'inc/db.php'; 
        //I have also tried include get_bloginfo("template_url")'/inc/db.php';
        //I have tried include 'db.php' and put db.php in root of site, root of theme folder.. nothing seems to pick it up.
    ?>
</head>
```

**inc/db.php**

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "dbname");
?>
```

**page-pricechanges.php**

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM dbname ORDER BY balance DESC") 
    or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1))
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = addslashes($row['name']);
        echo $id." ".$name."<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress has its own connection class, which can be used trough the [$wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb) object.

Is there a particular reason to use direct queries to the db, instead the wordpress functions ([get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_posts), [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_post_meta), [get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_option))? Keep in mind that by doing this, you loose a lot of the wordpress tools, such as cache, filters, etc...

Comment: The database I listed isn't a wordpress one. It's a fantasy football stats database. All I'm trying to do is create a custom page which shows all the numbers from the MySQL Database in a HTML table. I didn't know about $wpdb... Can I set this up for my own databases? I'll check it out now.

Comment: That can also be done with the wpdb class: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1618/33558

Comment: Great thanks - I wasn't aware. I'll take a look now. That looks like it will solve my problem.