# Using 'mysqli_connect' 'crashes' Wordpress client-side

Tags: plugins, php, mysql

I am using Wordpress as a CMS for a bus-route planner, I have inputted the first few bus stops for the first bus route and am now developing a PHP script for the planner.

I am using this code, with a plugin that allows the use of PHP in Wordpress pages (providing they're surrounded with the [php] [/php] tag):

```
[php]
    if (mysqli_connect([db details removed]))
    {
        echo 'Connected to database!';
    } else {
        echo "Failed to connect!";
    }
[/php]
```

The result of implementing this connection is that the page 'crashes': it displays nothing, but has the page title:

[image]

Without the `mysqli_connect`, the page looks like this:

[image]

Yes, it may have a few formatting errors, but that's not the point here.

Why is Wordpress 'crashing' client-side when I attempt to connect to a MySQL database? For the record, the database is separate from the one Wordpress uses; perhaps Wordpress doesn't allow connecting to two different databases at the same time?

Furthermore, how can I connect to my MySQL database properly without causing this 'crash'?

Comment: I'm betting it's the plugin, just use a custom template (http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) and assign that page to it if you need to execute arbitrary php.  WordPress is not restricting you from connecting to another database.  Edit: Though, you might consider consolidating them, WordPress has some good db connecting/interaction wrappers in the wpdb class so you can avoid doing all the legwork yourself.

Comment: @AndrewBartel Actually turned out to be a typo, but however I used ialocin's method just to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you could and should use [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to connect to another database. E.g. like this:

```
$the_other_db = new wpdb(
    'username',
    'password',
    'database',
    'localhost'
);
$results = $the_other_db->get_results( $sql );
```

Take a look at [Using wpdb to connect to a separate database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1604/22534) for more information.

Secondly, like @AndrewBartel said it's likely the plugin. Besides IMHO - not insult intended - inputting PHP code like this into the templating area will always be pretty awful. So going with a custom template and some class(es) and/or function(s) for your functionality would just be the much better approach.