# List table not rendering when $this->items is filled

Tags: admin-menu, wp-list-table

I'm attempting to add a [list table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_List_Table) to a custom admin page. I've been following [this guide](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/03/native-admin-tables-wordpress/) and [this reference implementation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-list-table-example/).

Unfortunately when I define `$this->items` to add the data, **nothing** displays in the admin page (not even the html around the list table) and there are no error messages. If I comment that line out (line `135`), then it works except for the obvious lack of data.

My code:

```
<?php

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_example_menues');

function add_example_menues() {
    add_menu_page('test', 'test', 'administrator', 'test-top', 'build_test_page');
    add_submenu_page('test-top', 'All tests', 'All tests', 'administrator', 'test-top');
}

if(!class_exists('WP_List_Table')){
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class test_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( array(
            'singular' => 'test',
            'plural' => 'tests',
            'ajax' => false
        ));
    }


    function extra_tablenav ($which) {
        if ($which == "top") {
            echo "Top";
        }
        if ($which == "bottom") {
            echo "Bottom";
        }
    }

    function get_columns() {
        $columns = array(
            'id'    => 'ID',
            'title'     => 'Title',
            'user_id'   => 'User ID',
            'description'   => 'Description'
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    function get_sortable_columns() {
        return $sortable = array(
            'id'        => array('id',false),
            'title'         => array('title',false),
            'user_id'       => array('user_id',false)
        );
    }

    function prepare_items() {
        global $wpdb;

        //data normally gotten from non-wp database. Wordpress db user has access, as per this SE post:
        //http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database
        $query = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `user_id`, `description` FROM otherdb.example_table";

        //pagination stuff
        $orderby = !empty($_GET["orderby"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["orderby"]) : 'ASC';
        $order = !empty($_GET["order"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["order"]) : '';
        if(!empty($orderby) & !empty($order)){ $query.=' ORDER BY '.$orderby.' '.$order; }
        $totalitems = $wpdb->query($query);
        echo "$totalitems";
        $per_page = 5;
        $paged = !empty($_GET["paged"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["paged"]) : '';
        if(empty($paged) || !is_numeric($paged) || $paged<=0 ){ $paged=1; }
        $totalpages = ceil($totalitems/$perpage);
        if(!empty($paged) && !empty($perpage)){
            $offset=($paged-1)*$perpage;
            $query.=' LIMIT '.(int)$offset.','.(int)$perpage;
        }
        $this->set_pagination_args( array(
            "total_items" => 4,
            "total_pages" => 1,
            "per_page" => 5,
        ) );


        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();

        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);

        //actual data gotten from database, but for SE use hardcoded array
        //$data = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_N);

        $example_data = array(
                array(
                        'id'        => 1,
                        'title'     => 'nonsense',
                        'user_id'    => 1,
                        'description'  => 'asdf'
                ),
                array(
                        'id'        => 2,
                        'title'     => 'notanumber',
                        'user_id'    => 2,
                        'description'  => '404'
                ),
                array(
                        'id'        => 3,
                        'title'     => 'I Am A Title',
                        'user_id'    => 3,
                        'description'  => 'desc'
                ),
                array(
                        'id'        => 4,
                        'title'     => 'Example',
                        'user_id'    => 4,
                        'description'  => 'useless'
                ),
                array(
                        'id'        => 5,
                        'title'     => 'aeou',
                        'user_id'    => 5,
                        'description'  => 'keyboard layouts'
                ),
                array(
                        'id'        => 6,
                        'title'     => 'example data',
                        'user_id'    => 6,
                        'description'  => 'data example'
                ),
                array(
                        'id'        => 7,
                        'title'     => 'last one',
                        'user_id'       => 7,
                        'description'  => 'done'
                )
            );


        //This is the line:
        $this->items = $example_data;
        //When the above line is commented, it works as expected (except for the lack of data, of course)
    }
}


function build_test_page() {

    $testListTable = new test_List_Table();
    $testListTable->prepare_items();

?>
<div class="wrap">

    <div id="icon-users" class="icon32"><br/></div>
    <h2>List Table Test</h2>

    <?php $testListTable->display() ?>

</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

The above code is in a separate file, included into `functions.php` with a  `require_once()`.

I'm using wordpress 4.1.1

What is going on here? Why would *everything* disappear and no error be given?

Comment: They have written in codex, that the class could change and dev's should have copied this class for non-problematic table render XD>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did same error first time I implemented `WP_List_Table`.

The problem is that when you call `WP_List_Table::display()` WordPress in turn calls:

- [WP_List_Table::display_rows_or_placeholder()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/display_rows_or_placeholder/)
- [WP_List_Table::display_rows()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/display_rows/)
- [WP_List_Table::single_row()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/single_row/)
- [WP_List_Table::single_row_columns()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/single_row_columns/)

Last function is called for every row. If you look at its code (see [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/19dbf7b998019ec87f7088339945d1c56f4b86d7/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L1073-L1087)), it has:

```
if ( 'cb' == $column_name ) {
   // you don't have 'cb' column, code remove because not relevant
} elseif ( method_exists( $this, 'column_' . $column_name ) ) {
   // you don't have method named 'column_{$column_name}',
   // code remove because not relevant 
} else {
   // not relevant line
   echo $this->column_default( $item, $column_name );
}
```

So WordPress calls `WP_List_Table::column_default()` for every row, but... that method [**doesn't exist**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/).

Add to your class:

```
public function column_default($item, $column_name) {
    return $item[$column_name];
}
```

And your data will be correctly displayed.

When you don't add data, error doesn't show up because with no data WordPress never calls `display_rows()` and other methods after that.

---

### Bonus Notes:

1. In your `prepare_items()` method you use the variable `$perpage` but you define it as `$per_page` (notice the underscore), that cause a division-by-zero warning (and pagination doesn't work)
2. the code `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["orderby"])` is **not** safe, because for `'orderby'` SQL clause `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not enough. (see [recent Yoast SQL injection bug](https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/7841)).

   Do something like:

   ```
   $orderby = 'id'; // default
   $by = strtolower(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'orderby', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
   if (in_array($by, array('title', 'description', 'user_id'), true) {
       $orderby = $by;
   }
   ```

   and do something similar to for `'order'` clause as well: very probably it can only be either `ASC` or `DESC`: don't allow anything else.

Comment: Damn, you beat me by seconds.. :)

Comment: @ialocin :) Well, I knew the answer just 1 sec after reading the question, but I spent 10+ minutes in writing to add all the formatting and the links in the right place.

Comment: Haha, yeah me too, I mean I spend some time on rewriting. Of course I had to look it up, otherwise I would have known 4 hours ago..

Comment: I did this error 1st time I wrote a WP_List_Table, so I recognized it immediately :)

Comment: Now I will remember too :) But there is THE difference I might be capable, but you have much more actual knowledge - besides being much more capable too of course :) Anyway its answered and solved! I'm happy :)

Answer (score 2):

Now at home, I actually ran your code. I got this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function convert_to_screen() in
>   .../wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php
>   on line 88

**Note:**

> Please turn on [Debugging_in_WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) when developing.

Anyway this lead me to the following question on *Stackoverflow*:

- [Wordpress WP List Table Implemantation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371861/wordpress-wp-list-table-implemantation)

@brasofilo's answer helped a lot, not surprising as he is one of the leading people on *WordPress Development* too.

Anyway following his answer, you are missing the method `column_default`, additionally the `_construct` method is different. But you can read that up yourself, here is some working - stripped down - code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_test_list_table_menues' );
function add_test_list_table_menues() {
    add_menu_page(
        'test', 
        'test', 
        'manage_options', 
        'test-top', 
        'test_list_table_output'
    );
}

function test_list_table_output() { 
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h2>Test List Table</h2>';
    new Test_List_Table(); 
    echo '</div>';
}

if( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class Test_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( array(
            'singular' => 'test',
            'plural' => 'tests',
            'ajax' => false
        ));
        $this->prepare_items();
        $this->display();
    }

    function get_columns() {
        $columns = array(
            'tid'    => 'ID',
            'title'     => 'Title',
            'user_id'   => 'User ID',
            'description'   => 'Description'
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
        switch( $column_name ) {
            case 'tid':
            case 'title':
            case 'user_id':
            case 'description':
                return $item[ $column_name ];
            default:
                return print_r( $item, true ) ;
        }
    }

    function prepare_items() {
        $example_data = array(
                array(
                        'tid'        => 1,
                        'title'     => 'nonsense',
                        'user_id'    => 1,
                        'description'  => 'asdf'
                ),
                array(
                        'tid'        => 2,
                        'title'     => 'notanumber',
                        'user_id'    => 2,
                        'description'  => '404'
                ),
                array(
                        'tid'        => 3,
                        'title'     => 'I Am A Title',
                        'user_id'    => 3,
                        'description'  => 'desc'
                ),
                array(
                        'tid'        => 4,
                        'title'     => 'Example',
                        'user_id'    => 4,
                        'description'  => 'useless'
                ),
                array(
                        'tid'        => 5,
                        'title'     => 'aeou',
                        'user_id'    => 5,
                        'description'  => 'keyboard layouts'
                ),
                array(
                        'tid'        => 6,
                        'title'     => 'example data',
                        'user_id'    => 6,
                        'description'  => 'data example'
                ),
                array(
                        'tid'        => 7,
                        'title'     => 'last one',
                        'user_id'       => 7,
                        'description'  => 'done'
                )
            );

        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();
        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
        $this->items = $example_data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too bad, probably too obvious.. @gandalf3

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tip. I'd accept both if I could!

Comment: No worries! @gandalf3

Comment: If you run this code on the latest version of WP (4.4.2), it still breaks and shows the "Call to undefined function convert_to_screen()" error FYI

Comment: Well, the only thing I can say at the moment is, I'm pretty sure it worked back then. Thanks for notifying me though, I try to come back to this soon. @AndyLobel