# How to customize default wordpress search query

Tags: search

I want to customize default search query in wordpress

I want search default data in another database.

Now I have 2 databases , one for wordpress and another base with copy of wp_posts content.

I want to change search query to secondary database.

How to do it via function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1618/99217)

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($rows as $obj) :
  echo "<li>".$obj->Name."</li>";
endforeach;
echo "</ul>";
```