# How do I configure WordPress to talk to a Microsoft SQL Server database?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, microsoft, mssql

We have are building a WordPress site on our intranet site and wish to connect it to a Microsoft SQL Server.

I have downloaded and configured PHP and PHP Manager on IIS.

I have also downloaded SQL Server DLL from the list of answered questions that popped on as I was typing the title of this thread.

I downloaded those DLLs inside the PHP folder as instructed.

When I fired up the server address to install WordPress, I was prompted to provide SQL DB name, username, password and DB hostname.

I have also downloaded wp-db-Abstraction plugin, put the wp-db-abstraction.php file into the folder where the WordPress files are saved, put the wp-db-abstraction folder into wp_content as instructed by the online article I was reading. Inside this folder, there is a db.php file. I also copied this db.php file into foldername where the rest of the downloaded WordPress files reside.

When I clicked to continue, I got the following error messages:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in E:\foldername\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1538

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in E:\foldername\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1569
Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in E:\foldername\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1569

Error establishing a database connection
```

What is weird about the error is that it is coming from WP_Includes folder where there is another wp-db.php. This folder came with the WordPress downloaded files.

The weird thing is that the error above is coming from wp-db.php file, not from the db.php file I downloaded.

Am I supposed to remove db.php include file from the list?

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: This is a php question, not a WordPress specific question for which you should seek an answer on the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) site which has several similar questions already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632607/how-to-use-php-to-connect-to-sql-server).

Comment: @Aurovrata, come on dude. That's where I posted the question and I got voted down because they said it is stackexchange.com question.

What the heck is wrong here?

Comment: Well, if you are installing separate php libraries in your WordPress installation folder then its a php question, I don't understand why you expect WordPress devs to answer that one for you.  On the other hand if you want to use the WordPress framework to make a custom db connection then you ought to change your question to reflect that.  I am trying to help you increase your chances of finding as answer here, no hard feelings!

Comment: For example, here is a WP specific question of someone trying to achieve soemthing similar, and they got see this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database#1618).

Comment: @Aurovrata, just for clarity, I do not have issues connecting PHP to sql server.

Infact, I have done that many times throughout my career. My issue is configuring wordpress to connect to SQL Server.

Specifically, there is a file called wp-db.php inside wp-includes to gets called when I tried to test wordpress db setup. That's the file that is spitting out the error messages posted above.

The link you referenced talks specifically to connecting to another MySQL.

Comment: It is now clearer that you want to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server, and not simply any sql server. Good luck with that!  There is apparently a plugin that allows you to abstract the sql server (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574698/wordpress-with-sql-server)), have you tried that?  There is also a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2d3GEyDoMI) video tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a new approach to it:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/05/12/running-wordpress-on-sql-server/

You can also use a 3rd party version of WordPress (*not my cup of tea, by the way*):

- https://code.google.com/archive/p/wordpress-mssql/
- https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami

Or follow this guide, but it might be a bit old:

- https://blog.building-blocks.com/installing-wordpress-on-windows-using-sql-server-2008-r2-part-1/

In the end I think the first link would be the best approach. Please comment if you have any problem during the installation.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but link only answers may be deleted as they become unhelpful once the links go dead. Please consider [editing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/323113/edit) your answer and then paste in the relevant solution, supplementing it with a link to the source.

Comment: @DaveRomsey, you are so right... but I don't have time to do that (screenshot, tests, etc...). Do you want me to delete the post?