# Connect to Ms SQL Server

Tags: sql, server, remote

I've been asked to develop custom plugins which will connect to a database hosted on MS SQL Server in different geographical location, i.e the website is hosted with a hosting service and the database is hosted within the businesses office. I have no idea how to go about remotely connecting the SQL server. Any advice people may offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question have been answered here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/312060/how-do-i-configure-wordpress-to-talk-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-database. Hope this can help you resolve your problem

Comment: I'm not sure that's the same thing - that sounds like it's trying to run the entire site from a SQL server, whereas it sounds to me like OP just wants to fetch extra data from a separate database.

Comment: I think you'll just have to follow whatever the normal process is for connecting to SQL Server from PHP. Unless you're trying to move the WordPress tables into SQL Server too then it'll be a separate not-WordPress-managed connection.

Comment: check with this https://projectnami.org/

Answer (score 1):

You have probably figured it out by now, but just in case. I was also asked to pull data from an MS SQL server and present the data on a WordPress site. In my plugin, I stored the connection values (encrypted) as options. Here are the basics.

Connection Function:

```
public function rimsdb() {
        global $rimsdb;
        
        $options = get_option('lwd_gs_plugin_options');

        $serverName = $options['db_host']; //serverName\instanceName
        $connectionInfo = array("Database" => $options['db_name'], "UID" => $options['db_user'], "PWD" => $options['db_password']);
        $rimsdb = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if ($rimsdb) {
            echo "Connection established.<br />";
        } else {
            echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    }

add_action( 'init', 'rimsdb' );
```

Below is a sample query

```
$params = array('my_value');

$sql1 = "SELECT col1, col2, col3
                    FROM mytable
                    WHERE col1 = ?";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($rimsdb, $sql1, $params);
        
        sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
        if ($stmt === false) {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $values = $row;
        }
```