# Is it possible to query from external database?

Tags: wp-query, database, query, sql

I have an extarnal database that I want to show some data in my wordpress site. What are the necessary steps to achieve this?

edit: I changed config.inc.php according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801573/how-to-access-remote-server-with-local-phpmyadmin-client but it enabled me to see the hostName of the external server visible by phpmyadmin. With the wordpress root I can enter the external database.

Up to here is good. But I do not have any clue about how to advance. I searched plugin to show the new database but I could not find any. I am new to the wordpress, so pardon me for my beginner questions. I want to show the data in different pages, with the unique string name that is the same as in the external database, ie: page name is the specifier query name.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on what you're trying to achieve?  WordPress is built on PHP so you can use regular PHP to access any database you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use wpdb to setup a new connection.

Add something similar to this below in your functions.php and you can then query just like you would normally but using the new connection.

```
$second_db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $database_name, DB_HOST);
$results = $second_db->get_results($your_query);
```

references:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1673/86845

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36759606/3204142