# Integrate separate web app inside wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, core

I want to integrate a wordpress installation with a third party application, it's an [online football game simulation](https://github.com/ihofmann/open-websoccer).
Is it possible to wrap it inside my wordpress installation, but with a separate database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be doable. And you should be able to leverage `wpdb`, with new instance, to connect to the separate database. Have a look at this old question, [Using wpdb to connect to a separate database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database).