# Wordpress API standard compliance and specification for external database

Tags: database, rest-api, api

HOW TO CONNECT WORDPRESS WITH EXTERNAL DB SERVER VIA API?

Comment: I don't understand what what the REST API documentation has to do with writing a "Wordpress API to link up external database.". What are you trying to do here?

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make a lot of sense: "can write API for our Wordpress 5.x site in order to access this external db server". Where is this API being created? Is the API for you to pull data to your site? If so, the API would not be a WordPress API so the WordPress REST API documentation would be irrelevant. If they're using the existing REST API on your website to remotely insert data to your site, then why are you asking for the documentation. Isn't that their job?

Comment: I have no idea. It's not at all clear to me what they want to do here. You'd need to ask them. What sent you here? Did they ask you for something? If so, you should share _exactly_ what they asked for, otherwise it's difficult to help.

Comment: There's just not enough information in that question to understand what you need. You're going to need to discuss with them their requirements in more detail.

Comment: ok, thanks for replies so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has the HTTP API that you could perhaps use to send POST (`wp_remote_post`) or GET (`wp_remote_get`) requests to an API, https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/. But you could also use cURL to send the requests, I think.

If the API is developed by you, then it's up to you to decide what kind of arguments the API accepts/expects and what kind of authentication it requires. If it's some 3rd party API, then you need to consult the API documentation to see what is needed to get a response from it and in which form you'll get the response - e.g. is it a JSON response.

Or if you can skip the API and connect directly to the database, then you could perhaps use `$wpdb` to do it as described here, [Using wpdb to connect to a separate database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database)

Comment: Thanks Antti. I think the 2nd paragraph is what really happening.
It is a 3rd party API (not yet done yet, the developer is asking what needs to comply with or requirement by the Wordpress site, when they write the connect-external-database-API). They will return with JSON response. Should I just tell them to write a REST compliant JSON API for Wordpress to use?