# how to access 2nd Mysqli Database from different server for wordpress

Tags: database, mysql

hello I have an old website https://www.manthanpublication.com/manthantest hosted using Codeigniter
as it is hard to customize I decide to change to Wordpress now the problem is I have student result on old website server. I want to access them on Wordpress website, I have PHP scripts from old website to run them on Wordpress but I don't know how to get or access 2nd MySQL database on Wordpress so I can show the student result on Wordpress website
new website https://manthanwelfarefoundation.org/

I hope you understand the question/problem if you need an explanation, please ask.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of the wpdb object. It is explained in many posts like this one:  [Using wpdb to connect to a separate database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database)

Comment: `$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($rows as $obj) :
   echo "<li>".$obj->Name."</li>";
endforeach;
echo "</ul>";`    i tried that but want to access different server not localhost